# Why did I get a Legendary Card from an arena of a higher level?

Tags: clash-royale

I got a Legendary Card from a chest that would have been given in the arena for reaching a certain amount of trophies, but that card is from an arena of a higher level than mine (which should be locked).
Is this a bug, or do Legendary Cards differ from other cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a legendary chest, you can get legendaries from any arena.